# Difference between from inspect import stack and from numpy import stack

Tags: python, stack

While implementing stack I get two import option and I was unable to get what is the difference between them?

```
from inspect import stack
s = stack()

l = [1, 2, 3, 45, 5]
sum = 0
for i in l:
    s.append(i)
    sum = sum + i

avg = sum / len(s)
s.append(avg)
for i in s:
    print(i)
```

Getting output:

```
FrameInfo(frame=<frame object at 0x7fb51436d828>, filename='/home/alok/PycharmProjects/New/StackImp.py', lineno=2, function='<module>', code_context=['s = stack()\n'], index=0)
1
2
3
45
5
9.333333333333334
```

Comment: Read [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/inspect.html#inspect.stack). And [these](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html). Hint: You don't want to use either one of those functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**: They have nothing in common.

#### [numpy.stack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html):

A function that *stacks* one array on top of another.

#### [inspect.stack](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.stack):

A function that gives you access to the *call stack* of the function being executed.

#### [Actual stack data structure](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#using-lists-as-stacks):

In python, you can use a list as a stack (as shown in the linked document) by using `list.append()` and `list.pop()` methods of the `list` type.

**Recapping**: These three things have nothing in common, they apply to entirely different use-cases.